# httpconnection.getResponseCode() giving EOF exception

Tags: http, networking, blackberry

I am using `Httconnection` for connecting to webserver , somtimes request fails causing

`EOFException` when calling httpconnection.getResponseCode().

I am setting the following headers while making the connection

```
HttpConnection httpconnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url.concat(";interface=wifi"));
httpconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
httpconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

I am closing all the connections after processing the request properly.Is this exception is due to  exceeding max connections.

Comment: Hmm.  Are you 100% sure it was EOFException and not IOException?

Comment: is it something like this: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2005Oct/0057

Comment: @Fostah, seems like it's possible, EOF exception at server goes as Error 500, internal server error and returns as a response code

Comment: @coldice That seems to make sense, but I don't think that would be identified on the phone/app side as a EOFException as 500 is a general Internal Server Error. Either way the question definitely reads as if the phone app is throwing the exception.

Comment: srinivas-g, please clarify, are you getting "Error 500 EOF" as a String value from httpconnection.getResponseMessage(), or there is a real EOFException throwing in you code?

Answer (score 2):

It's an internal server error, which return [status code 500](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1) in response.

This may be caused by incorrect request, but as well server code or overload may be the reason.
If you have access to server, check event logs.

See also
[500 EOF when chunk header expected](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2005Oct/0057)
[Why might LWP::UserAgent be failing with '500 EOF'?](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=543006)
[500 EOF instead of reponse status line in perl script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/500-eof-instead-of-reponse-status-line-in-perl-script-552805/)
[Apache 1.3 error - Unexpected EOF reading HTTP status - connectionreset](http://objectmix.com/weblogic/552570-apache-1-3-error-unexpected-eof-reading-http-status-connectionreset.html)
[Error 500!](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php?topic=28473.0)

**UPDATE** On the other hand, if it's not response message, but a real exception, then it may be simply a bug, [just like in old java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4191815)
And workaround may be putting getResponseCode() inside of try/catch and call second time on exception:

```
    int responseCode = -1;
    try {
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException ex1) {
        //check if it's eof, if yes retrieve code again
        if (-1 != ex1.getMessage().indexOf("EOF")) {
            try {
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
                System.out.println(ex2.getMessage());
                // handle exception
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Talking by connections number limit, read
[What Is - Maximum number of simultaneous connections](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Maximum_number_of_simultaneous_connections.html?nodeid=1167277&vernum=0)
[How To - Close connections](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Close_connections.html?nodeid=1261294&vernum=0)

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPTransportSE, write this before invoke the method "call"

```
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertyArrayList);
```